# Editable datagrid in windows mobile compact framework c#

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework

So I am trying to add editable column to datagrid. I followed msdn sample at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms838165.aspx 
 which works, up to a point when I'm trying to type in data to the textbox, which kinda defies the whole point.  I tried to set focus() property to the textbox, yet no results.
I'm using compact framework 3.5.

150 lines of code can be found here, if someone is willing to try it - http://pastebin.com/08bz8scH

Can you please tell what am i doing wrong? Here is important code sample:

```
    private void dataGrid1_CurrentCellChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!inUpdateMode)
        {
            if (inEditMode && !dataGrid1.CurrentCell.Equals(editCell))
            {
                // Update edited cell
                inUpdateMode = true;
                dataGrid1.Visible = false;
                DataGridCell currentCell = dataGrid1.CurrentCell;
                dataGrid1[editCell.RowNumber, editCell.ColumnNumber] =
                  txtEdit.Text;
                dataGrid1.CurrentCell = currentCell;
                dataGrid1.Visible = true;
                inUpdateMode = false;
                txtEdit.Visible = false;
                inEditMode = false;
                bool ff = dataGrid1.TableStyles.IsReadOnly;
            }

            // Enter edit mode
            editCell = dataGrid1.CurrentCell;
            txtEdit.Text = ""; //(string)dataGrid1[editCell.RowNumber,editCell.ColumnNumber];
            System.Drawing.Rectangle cellPos = dataGrid1.GetCellBounds(editCell.RowNumber,
              editCell.ColumnNumber);
            txtEdit.Left = cellPos.Left ;
            txtEdit.Top = cellPos.Top + dataGrid1.Top ;
            txtEdit.Width = cellPos.Width ;
            txtEdit.Height = cellPos.Height ;
            txtEdit.Visible = true;
            txtEdit.Focus();
            inEditMode = true;
        }


    }
```

Comment: it might be because txtEdit has no parent

Comment: It does, main form is the parent. Maybe I should try with datagrid as its parent?

Comment: This solved my problem 
 if (!dataGrid1.Controls.Contains(tmpTextBox))
                    dataGrid1.Controls.Add(tmpTextBox);

Comment: Check out my project, I have an editable datagrid with various editable column types https://b2kui.codeplex.com/